# Receive error when using Scribe's OData Connector

Tags: odata, crm, microsoft-dynamics, scribe-workbench

I'm pretty new to the Scribe world.  We've developed a custom oData endpoints using Web API 2.2 to expose data from our internal systems so that we can import it into our CRM Online environment using Scribe.  When we try to test our connection in Scribe we get an error that we really do not understand.

The Connection test failed.

Verify that the associated connection information is valid and that you have access to this oData service.

The following exception message was returned from the oData service:

> No model was specified for the oDataMessageReader. A message reader requires a model for JSON light payload to be specified in the oDataMessageReader constructor.

I'm wondering if there is anyone out there whose written their own endpoint and was successfully able to connect to it using Scribe's OData connector.  If so, any advise would be greatly appreciated or a point in the right direction as to a possible cause of the error.  I keep searching the net and cant find any leads.  I'm also showing an example of our response payload.  if there is anything odd in there, i'd like to know.

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"https://extranet.trimontrea.com/Skynet/odata/$metadata#EntitiesOData","value":[
    {
      "EntityID":"1","EntityName":"LEHMAN BROTHERS HOLDING INC             ","Address1":"200 VESEY ST, 12TH FLOOR      ","Address2":"                              ","Address3":"                              ","Address4":"NEW YORK, NY  10285           ","City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"PrimaryContact":"LEHMAN BROTHERS HOLDINGS INC  ","EntityType":null,"TaxID":"","PhoneNumber":"","FaxNumber":""
    },{
      "EntityID":"10","EntityName":"RESTRUCTURED ASSET SECURITIES2          ","Address1":"C/O THE BANK OF NEW YORK      ","Address2":"WHITE CLAY CENTER             ","Address3":"NEWARK, DELAWARE              ","Address4":"19711                         ","City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"PrimaryContact":"CDC II                        ","EntityType":null,"TaxID":"","PhoneNumber":"","FaxNumber":""
    },{
      "EntityID":"100","EntityName":"LBHI - OLD GATE                         ","Address1":"LBHI - OLD GATE               ","Address2":"                              ","Address3":"                              ","Address4":"                              ","City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"PrimaryContact":"                              ","EntityType":null,"TaxID":"","PhoneNumber":"","FaxNumber":""
    },{
      "EntityID":"101","EntityName":"LBHI - OLD GATE EQUITY                  ","Address1":"LBHI - OLD GATE EQUITY        ","Address2":"                              ","Address3":"                              ","Address4":"                              ","City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"PrimaryContact":"                              ","EntityType":null,"TaxID":"","PhoneNumber":"","FaxNumber":""
    },{
      "EntityID":"11","EntityName":"PTG-LB BANKHAUS LONDON BRANCH           ","Address1":"3 WORLD FINANCIAL CENTER      ","Address2":"NEW YORK                      ","Address3":"NY                            ","Address4":"10285                         ","City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"PrimaryContact":"LONDON BRANCH                 ","EntityType":null,"TaxID":"","PhoneNumber":"","FaxNumber":""
    },{
      "EntityID":"12","EntityName":"LBHI - WATERTON CONDUIT LOANS           ","Address1":"200 VESEY ST, 12TH FLOOR      ","Address2":"PRINCIPAL TRANSACTIONS GROUP  ","Address3":"                              ","Address4":"NEW YORK, NY 10285            ","City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"PrimaryContact":"O/B/O WATERTON CONDUIT LOANS  ","EntityType":null,"TaxID":"","PhoneNumber":"","FaxNumber":""
    },{
      "EntityID":"13","EntityName":"ORIX REAL EST. CAP. MARKETS             ","Address1":"1717 MAIN STREET, 12TH FLOOR  ","Address2":"                              ","Address3":"                              ","Address4":"DALLAS, TX 75201              ","City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"PrimaryContact":"SASCO - SERIES 2000-C2        ","EntityType":null,"TaxID":"","PhoneNumber":"","FaxNumber":""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out I was passing in the wrong URL as the connection URL.  I should have passed in this:

https://extranet.trimontrea.com/Skynet/odata

and not

https://extranet.trimontrea.com/Skynet/odata/EntitiesOData